# Java : get method name form method invocation

Tags: java, reflection, delegates

I would to know if there is a way to retrieve the method name by a definition in this way

Eg :

```
 getMethodName ( MyObject.myMethod() ) -> "myMethod"
```

this because i would use a sort of C# delegate (achieved through java's reflection) but i'm afraid about the absence of compiler's checking, during method invocation.

But if i could retrieve safely the method's name , i should execute reflection without the risk of calling an unexisting method.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: getMethodName method is containing class name as parameter ??

Comment: Something like this for (Method method : YourClass.class.getDeclaredMethods()) {
    String name = method.getName();
}

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo in other word i asked if there is a way to identify a method,but reading your reply seems that there is no way to do that.


MyObject.class.getMehods() is good, but not enought to give to me information about a specific method, i mean there is no easy way to specify (safely) a method at design time, and obtain a compiler's guarantees that the method exits at runtime.

Comment: @Prince your example is pretty close to what i would.
Is there a way to do "Method m = myObject.someMethod()"? And then "m.toString()"?
If there is, it's exactly what i want.

Comment: There is a way to get methods and then there is a way to invoke method with params. What exactly do you want?

Comment: I would pass a method written as i try to invoke it (to ensure it exist), to an object that store and run it later, like C# delegate (because Java has no delegate i use reflection, but i need method name in a secure way).

I tried to explain it better in this post on pastebin
http://pastebin.com/49UzJFQL